# alamofire responseStreamString decode

Tags: swift, alamofire

recently started learning Swift :)

```
let req = AF.streamRequest(...)
req.responseStreamString { stream in
    switch stream.event {
    case let .stream(result):
          switch result {
          case let .success(string):
            print(string)
          case let .failure(error):
            print("failure")
              print(error)
          }
    case .complete(_): //
        print("complete")
    }
```

How do I get to the actual value I need without having to say picking out line 4 each time?

This is the output from `print(string)`

```
--eventStreamBoundary
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 23
20200428124609 5 X NULL
```

`20200428124609 5 X NULL` is the value I am after, do i need a custom decode or something built in already exists?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

`DataStreamRequest` merely provides the stream of `Data` (or parsed) values as they come in, it does no additional parsing itself beyond what `URLSession` provides automatically. You'll need to parse the response yourself. This can be encapsulated in a `DataStreamSerializer` rather than having to put all of the logic into a closure.

What kind of HTTP response format are your using?